# Why speed of trapz integration depends on input value magnitude?

Tags: matlab

I had small bug in my code in matlab, where i was starting integration loop from single value (instead of array).

I noticed that if i give trapz(1,1) it gives zero (as it should for trapz(x,y)) almost instantly, however time taken for it to calculate it depends wildly on the magnitude of 'y'.

That is:

```
tic;trapz(5.1000,1.6610e+03);toc
Elapsed time is 0.011022 seconds.

tic;trapz(5.1000,1.6610e+04);toc
Elapsed time is 0.485286 seconds.

tic;trapz(5.1000,1.6610e+05);toc
Elapsed time is 46.400199 seconds.

tic;trapz(5.1000,1.6610e+06);toc
..Still going on
```

I have no explanation for it. Why shall it matter what value is in input?

Comment: this similar to asking why a for loop that you change the limit but keep the step size the same takes longer as there are more iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two scalar inputs, [`trapz`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) interprets your call as

> `trapz(y,dim)` integrates across dimension `dim` of `y`

To integrate along that dimension, it applys a permutation with `permute`. As `dim` increases, that permutation is more costly. These are the relevant lines of `trapz` code:

> `perm = [dim:max(ndims(y),dim) 1:dim-1];` 
>   `y = permute(y,perm);`

Try timing them by themselves:

```
>> y = 5; dim = 1e3;
tic, perm = [dim:max(ndims(y),dim) 1:dim-1]; y = permute(y,perm); toc
Elapsed time is 0.001761 seconds.

>> y = 5; dim = 1e4;
tic, perm = [dim:max(ndims(y),dim) 1:dim-1]; y = permute(y,perm); toc
Elapsed time is 0.148300 seconds.

>> y = 5; dim = 1e5;
tic, perm = [dim:max(ndims(y),dim) 1:dim-1]; y = permute(y,perm); toc
Elapsed time is 17.534308 seconds.
```